# Loop over name line in bash file

Tags: bash, loops

I have a file name "list.txt" with employee names - most of them are "Raj",
I want to create a script in bash called "findRaj.sh" - the script should catch all "Raj" lines in the "list.txt" and store it in new a file called "newlist.txt",

I created the script with "nao findRaj.sh" as following:

```
#!/bin/bash
> newlist.txt
# i save the file name in variable call files
files=`grep ' jane ' ../data/list.txt`
#
if test -e ~/data/list.txt; then echo "File exists"; else echo "File doesn't exist"; fi
```

but I don't know to do this section

Since none of the files present in the file list.txt are available in the file system, check if file names present in files variable are actually present in the file system. To do this,  use the test
Now, iterate over the files variable and add a test expression within the loop. If the item within the files variable passes the test, add/append it to the file newlist.txt

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Please [format the code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) in your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your `$files` variable contains file names, you could simply do the below loop.
If the file exists, it will append its name into newlist.txt file

```
for file in $files 
do 
   if [ -f "$file" ]
   then 
       echo "$file" >> newlist.txt
   fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help , but I made little change to your code and that solve my problem after try your code it print the file empty - I change it as below

```
for file in $files 
do 
   if test -e ~/data/list.txt;
   then 
       echo "$file" >> newlist.txt
   fi
done
```